# Execute a function once for each ID

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-classic

I need to allow the function caller to only execute the function **once** **for each request ID**. So I have IDs and for each ID , the caller can only execute the function once. I need help in a way that is cost efficient to implement this in Ethereum. I am writing a smart contract using Solidity. Any ideas?

```
mapping(address=>bool) RegisteredOracles;
mapping(uint=>uint)ID_Timesatmp;//to store every request ID and its timestamp

 function ReturnContactTracingList(uint ID, uint timestamp) public{
    require(RegisteredOracles[msg.sender]);  //To be executed by registered oracles only
   
    require (ID_Timesatmp[ID] == timestamp);//using the ID sent by the oracle to verify the timestamp sent also by the oracle
    
}
```

Comment: Show your code please (not sure what made you think that anyone here would be able to answer this question without it)!

Comment: @goodvibration I just added the function that needs access restriction for each Oracle (Ethereum address) once per ID

Comment: I don't get it. An oracle can pass any ID and timestamp that it wants. What prevents an oracle from sending different values each time? Or do you trust the oracles not to do it, and you're simply looking for a way to use the (presumably-correct) input in order to restrict the access?

Comment: Also, there's a lot of missing context in your code. For example, what is `address_Timestamp`? Who sets entries in `ID_Timesatmp` and when?

Comment: The timestamp and IDs are created by the smart contract so they are correct, I only check the ones returned by the oracle to make sure they match the ones in the contract. I need to restrict the access now for each oracle only one per ID

Comment: `function ReturnContactTracingList(uint ID, uint timestamp) public` - anyone is free to pass any ID and/or timestamp that they want. So it sounds pretty easy to forge one's identity!

Comment: The oracles are awarded or penalized based on their results. Also, the timestamp should match the one in the contract. The IDs and timestamps are for events. Forging them by the oracles will only let the oracles be penalized. So I am not worried about that.

Comment: Please post all the relevant parts of your code.